# Simple dmenu launcher for passwords, docs, notes and application shortcuts (Python)

Tags: python, console, automation

I created a small script for automating password store management and quickly searching and launching notes, shortcuts and documents through some keybindings that will execute the script.

Script is working fine, but would very much appreciate feedback from more experienced folks on how to improve. I thought about using a configuration file instead of hard-coding the default directories, but not sure if really something worth it as its something that rarely changes.

The same code from below can also be found at the [following repository](https://github.com/fsilveir/dmenu-launch).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import argparse
import subprocess

from collections import namedtuple
from distutils.spawn import find_executable

def main():
    check_req_utils()

    args   = get_args()
    scheme = dmenu_setup(args)
    choice = dmenu_input(scheme)

    take_action(scheme, choice)

def check_req_utils():
    """Checks if dmenu and other mandatory utilities can be found on target machine."""
    utils = (['dmenu', 'gpg', 'pass', 'xclip', 'exo-open'])
    for util in utils:
        if find_executable(util) is None:
            print("ERROR: Util '{}' is missing, install it before proceeding! Exiting!").format(util)
            sys.exit(1)

def check_dir_exist(scheme):
    """Checks required directories are present."""
    if os.path.exists(scheme.prefix) is False:
        print("ERROR: Required directory '{}' is missing! Exiting!").format(scheme.prefix)
        sys.exit(1)

def get_args():
    """Return arguments from stdin or print usage instructions."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple dmenu launcher for passwords, notes and application shortcuts.')
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    
    group.add_argument('--pass', dest='passw', action='store_true', 
                        help='Copy password from password store.')
    group.add_argument('--apps', action='store_true',
                        help='Quick launches a desktop application with exo-open.')
    group.add_argument('--notes', action='store_true',
                        help='Opens a text/markdown note from a given directory with exo-open.')
    group.add_argument('--search', action='store_true',
                        help='Quick search and launch from a given directory with exo-open.')

    if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)

    return parser.parse_args()

def dmenu_setup(args):
    """Setup dmenu font, color and size based on user's input."""
    scheme = namedtuple(
                        'dmenu',
                         [
                          'target',             # pass / apps/ notes / search
                          'prefix',             # location prefix (base dir)
                          'suffix',             # file extension to look for
                          'font',               # dmenu font name and size
                          'nb','nf','sb','sf',  # dmenu color:
                                                #   n = normal / s = selected, 
                                                #   b = background, f = foreground
                         ])

    dmenu = ""
    if args.passw:
        dmenu = scheme(
                    target='pass',
                    prefix = os.getenv('PASSWORD_STORE_DIR',os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser('~/.password-store'))),
                    suffix=".gpg",
                    font='Dejavu Sans Mono:medium:size=18',
                    nb='#191919', nf='#ff0000', sb='#ff9318', sf='#191919',
                  )
    if args.apps:
        dmenu = scheme(
                    target='apps',
                    prefix="/usr/share/applications",
                    suffix=".desktop",
                    font='Dejavu Sans Mono:medium:size=18',
                    nb='#191919', nf='#2e9ef4', sb='#2e9ef4', sf='#191919',
                  )
    if args.notes:
        dmenu = scheme(
                    target='notes',
                    prefix=os.path.expanduser('~/git/notes'),
                    suffix=".md",
                    font='Dejavu Sans Mono:medium:size=18',
                    nb='#191919', nf='#2aa198', sb='#2aa198', sf='#191919',
                   )
    if args.search :
        dmenu = scheme(
                    target='search',
                    prefix=os.path.expanduser('~/work'),
                    suffix="",
                    font='Dejavu Sans Mono:medium:size=18',
                    nb='#191919', nf='#2aa198', sb='#2aa198', sf='#191919',
                   )
    check_dir_exist(dmenu)
    return dmenu

def dmenu_input(scheme):
    """Builds dmenu list of options and returns the value selected by user."""
    choices = []
    for basedir, dirs , files in os.walk(scheme.prefix, followlinks=True):
        dirs.sort()
        files.sort()
        
        dirsubpath = basedir[len(scheme.prefix):].lstrip('/')
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(scheme.suffix):
                full_path = os.path.join(dirsubpath, f.replace(scheme.suffix, '', -1))
                choices += [full_path]

    args = ["-fn", scheme.font, "-nb", scheme.nb, "-nf", scheme.nf, "-sb", scheme.sb, "-sf", scheme.sf, "-i" ]
    dmenu = subprocess.Popen(['dmenu'] + args,
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    choice_lines = '\n'.join(map(str, choices))
    choice, errors = dmenu.communicate(choice_lines.encode('utf-8'))
    
    if dmenu.returncode not in [0, 1] \
       or (dmenu.returncode == 1 and len(errors) != 0):
        print("'{} {}' returned {} and error:\n{}"
              .format(['dmenu'], ' '.join(args), dmenu.returncode,
                      errors.decode('utf-8')))
        sys.exit(1)
    
    choice = choice.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    return (scheme.prefix + "/" + choice + scheme.suffix) if choice in choices else sys.exit(1)

def take_action(scheme, choice):
    """Copies password to clipboard, launch app or notes depending on user's input."""
    if (scheme.target == "pass"):
        _target = (str(choice).replace(scheme.prefix,'',-1))
        target = (_target[1:].replace(scheme.suffix,'',-1))

        # Copies the username to middle button clipboard
        username = target.rsplit('/',1)[1].strip('\n')
        run_subprocess('echo "{}" | xclip'.format(username))
        
        # Copy password to clipboard for 45 seconds
        run_subprocess('pass show -c "{}"'.format(target))
    
    if (scheme.target == "notes"):
        run_subprocess('exo-open "{}"'.format(choice))
    
    if (scheme.target == "apps") or (scheme.target == "search"):
        run_subprocess('exo-open "{}"'.format(choice))

def run_subprocess(cmd):
    """Handler for shortening subprocess execution."""
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin =subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          shell=True,)

# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# EOF
```